# How do I create a Group Total from an existing group in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports that has several Groups as noted below.  I need to return a total for each Customer Group by the items (I could have 6 invoices that have Item 1 - 3 on each)I want to see a total for each item - rather than seeing 18 lines - just 3 aggregated by Item

Group1 Customer 
ABC001
XYZ002
DEF001

Group2 Invoice #
017700
017702
017703

Group3 Details from Items on Invoice (I needed this to load in taxes to Sales & COGS)
Item 1 
Item 2 
Item 3

Answer (score 0):

Insert a CrossTab in GH1 or GF1 that shows totals by Item.

note: could also be done with a subreport, but CrossTab is easier and faster.